# Creating SQLite Version from server MySQL db

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

Hi I need advice on how to create the sqlite db for my app.  You see, I have an app that connects to a server db in php/mysql platform. I need my android app to have an sqlite db that is a minimal version of the server db particularly only data that are relevant to the type of user using the app.

Some things I've considered:

1. Attach a pre-populated sqlite db to the APK. This one would certainly make the APK package big.
2. Create the sqlite db upon first time use of the app, connect to the server and extract necessary data to populate the sqlite db. I'm not sure how to do this as I usually use json to exctract data from server. This might also take so much time as each record will be inserted to the sqlite tables.
3. I was thinking of requesting the server to create a pre-populated sqlite db based on the latest set of data it has. Then the app would then download this generated sqlite db and transfer it to my android app.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated. If you have other suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would choose option 3: have server prepare SQLite db and compress it using zip or gzip or something like it. Depending on your data, SQLite database should compress 2x-5x from original size.

Then your apk would connect to server, download compressed SQLite db, uncompress it into application home directory (or SDcard if you have permission and desire to do so).

From this point on, you just connect to this db from your app. If you want to download updates, it would be better to not redownload whole database, but implement incremental updates. If server is smart enough, it could offer another smaller SQLite db with incremental updates only (also compressed). Or, it can offer textual SQL script (again, compressed), by executing which you get necessary updates (and possibly schema changes as well).

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the reply. I would then go with this approach and adding your suggestions as well especially the compression. Again, many thanks mvp